# IDEA Community Edition versus Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

How does the IDEA Community Edition compare with Eclipse?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IDEA is a far better IDE than Eclipse (general opinion by people that use IDEA).

On a feature point of view, everything that IDEA CE can also been done by Eclipse. However, 
IDEA is a commercial product, which limits its adoption. Thanks to the Community Edition, you can test this IDE for free, in order to develop JavaSE applications (or Scala or Groovy). For an enterprise, this is quite limited, as you will not be able to develop J2EE applications.

My conclusion is that IDEA CE is only a tool that allows you to test and understand the philosophy of this IDE. If you are convinced by IDEA, then you will really have to choose between the Ultimate Edition, which will let develop any kind of applications, or stay with Eclipse.

Comment: You will still be able to develop JavaEE applications with the community edition, you just won't get any specific help from the IDE as you would with the full version.

Comment: @dan:true but the point of using an IDE is to get code completion/highlight and error correction, and click thrus etc that IDEA provides. Otherwise, you'd be better off using VIM!

Answer (score 3):

The best, straight answer to this, is to look at the [feature matrix](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) of which features are still left in Ultimate-Edition. Eclipse probably has support for all of these things, although the quality of the integrations can always be an issue.

Comment: The link seems broken (syntax)

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/editions_comparison_matrix.html?utm_source=jetbrains.org&utm_medium=Comparison&utm_campaign=IDEA9_CE

Comment: That was actually the SO "url" box truncating my url. hacked the source ;)

Comment: @pimpf0r your link is also dead now ;) Working one is here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

Why IDEA:

- detects unused public fields and methods
- easy way to run or debug only one test method (you don't need to modify configuration)
- faster code coverage report generation (at least for EMMA)
- understand difference between source and test source
- easier way to manage libs - just include lib dir (in eclipse you have to specify all jars explicitly), so you don't have to update it manually every time when new jar was included